# Создать PDF-файл с библиотекой Itext из массива байтов

Tags: java, pdf, itext

У меня изначально байтовый массив. Мне нужно записать его в файл pdf вместе со шрифтами. Для этого я нашел рабочую библиотеку IText, которая позволяет это сделать. Но и там записывать только строковые значения, а не массив байтов. Если перевести массив в строку, вы получите изогнутые символы.

```
byte[] docBytes = documentService.createDocument(model);
Document document = new Document();
BaseFont helvetica = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(helvetica, 12, Font.NORMAL);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
document.open();
document.add(new Chunk(Arrays.toString(docBytes), font)); // TODO
document.close();
```

Как записать массив байтов в pdf с помощью этой библиотеки? (Мне он нужен и для передачи шрифтов в MiniO) Заранее спасибо, друзья!

Comment: Как именно ваш массив байт должен "выглядеть" внутри pdf файла? Вам нужно, чтобы он был виден при просмотре? Если да, то в каком виде?

Comment: я уже давно использую для конвертации в пдф https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf и вроде нормально

Comment: Решение в итоге было найдено ?